# Renaming Windows Toolbar application link

Tags: c#, windows, rename, toolbar

I'm working on Visual Studio 2019 with C# and i'm stuck with this technical matter. I want to change the name of my app displayed on Windows bottom toolbar.

I tried many things.
I changed the solution name.
I changed (i suppose) ANY possible location of that word in the files.
I changed the name in the application tab in the solution properties.
I changed the folder name and project name (opening the project file via notepad).
I removed obj and bin folders and cleansed/rebuilded.
I removed old files named with their old version (when i renamed things in visual studio, instead of renaming some files it created new files with the new name, so the old files with old name remained).
I already did this weeks and weeks ago, it worked...but never did it before and i was a bit confused and randomly trying. I thought the real thing was just opening the project via notepad and changing its content (so i even wrote myself a note to remember it), but it's not. I don't understand what i'm missing.

I did something useful by trying to play it as Release and not Debug, but i also managed weeks ago to change it as a Debug as well and just don't remember or understand how to do it.

Thank you in advance!

(Edit: i'm trying to edit it again to change a letter into Upper Case, but also running it into Release it doesn't change and stays Lower Case...definitely something goes wrong with all this)

Comment: What type of application is it? Usually it's the caption of the main window.

Comment: It's a normal desktop application with a form and various controls in it. I forgot, i changed also the Form caption/title/text, so that's not it :/